# fxFlex angular flex layout not working as expected version 7.0.0-beta.19

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7, angular-flex-layout

**Todo :**

- I want to have grid colum using `flex layout`:
- I tried with two differents version of `flex layout` 
  and it working fine using the version:
  **5.0.0-beta.13**

  See this stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-flex-layout-seed-working-flex

  But not working with version **7.0.0-beta.19 or 6.x.x**

  See here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fx-layout-testing

Here is my code and what i tried:

```
<div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutGap="32px" fxLayoutAlign="start start">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let _ of [1,2,3,4,5,6]">
    <p fxFlex="0 1 calc(33.3% - 32px)">Flex</p>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

The documentation not provide a breaking change inside the api. 
Has someone an idea what is going wrong here ? 
or should i open an issue on github ?

Comment: The first stackblitz isn't working for me, so I can't see what your desired output is. But I you want the 'Flex' to be on a row, I would use `span` instead of `p`

Comment: Hey your first stackblitz isnt working for me but the second. Did you maybe acctually switch them ?

Comment: sorry i edited the link

Comment: @Mel It should work for block elements. I edited my first link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to import FlexLayoutModule in app.module.ts

```
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, FlexLayoutModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: This was the cause of my problem too, thanks. It's surprising how many times that unexpected runtime behaviour is caused by missing modules or slightly out-of-sync ng build.